# How to access all data in a firestore database with admin approval?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am currently building a `vuejs` web app that uses `firestore` from `firebase`. The basic structure is a user fills out an application with data and then an admin can look at that data to see if they are eligible for funding. The problem that I am encountering is that when the admin requests the information from `firestore`, it only ever returns an empty array.

The admin tag is assigned using this `firebase` cloud function:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  //get user and add custom claim (admin)

  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      admin: true
    });
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin`
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

My `firestore` structure is as follows:

```
users
 |_user1_uid
   |_info
 |_user2_uid
    |_info
```

The call I am making to get the information is this:

```js
db.collection('users')
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
     console.log(snapshot.docs)
  })
```

As you can see, the call is supposed to get a snapshot of all of the documents I have. (example: the `console.log` should show that I have three users `> (3) [n, n, n]`). However, what is returned instead is an empty array.

My `firestore` rules are this:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
      }

    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or pointers on why my admin is unable to get the users' information would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you need any more info, please let me know

Comment: So you're saying the console.log() does get executed and prints an empty array?

Comment: exactly! And I found if I create a dummy document with an auto-ID inside of `firestore` manually, my code is able to get that document. That's why I think it might be a security rules problem.

Comment: Security rules will either reject that entire query, or return all the documents.  There is no middle ground.

Comment: really? Then I am now even more confused. because I can see the documents, but they aren't being returned. could it have something to do with the fact that the userId is name of each doc?

Comment: Without seeing the actual data and comparing it to the code, there's no way of knowing.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of a sample document that works and one that does not work?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I will test my theory then answer it myself

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what was happening. When I start making my documents I was using this code:

```js
db.collection('users').doc(this.uid)
  .collection('info').doc('county').set({
     county: this.county
  )}
```

What I didn't realize is that this makes the document that holds `this.uid` to be virtual. If I had looked a little harder I would have seen this notification on `firebase`:

[image: notification of virtual document]

I found a relatively simple workaround which was first creating the UID document with dummy data before adding actual info to it like so:

```js
db.collection('users').doc(this.uid).set({
  dummy: 'dummy'
})
```

This fixed my problem. Thanks everyone for your help! I appreciate it!